# How to set the target of the near turtle and follow it when world is not allowed to wrap (without going througt the walls)

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem with following the nearest candida (breed) by another turtle - neutrophil (breed). Candidas can't move and neutrophil looks for the nearest candida in the area, face to him and go forward. Everything is fine when world is allowed to wrap. Then neutrophils go througt the "walls" and chase candida. 
BUT the point is that world can't wrap.
So I created condidion with help another model, which bounce the neutrophil, when they reach one of the max coordinates. But now they keep bouncing from the walls and don't looking for another target.

I will be very thankful for help.

```html
to lookfor  ;;if meet candida in near area - chase, if not - continue looking for
  ifelse any? candidas [ chase ] [ move ]
end

to chase  ;;set the target on the nearest candida, face to them and move one step to him
  set nearest-candidas min-one-of candidas [ distance myself ]
  face nearest-candidas
  bounce fd 1
end

to move
  bounce
  fd 2
end

to bounce
   if abs pxcor = max-pxcor   [ set heading (- heading) ]  ;; bounce off top and bottom walls
   if abs pycor = max-pycor   [ set heading (180 - heading) ]
   if abs pzcor = max-pzcor   [ set heading (- heading) ]
   set nearest-candidas max-one-of candidas [ distance myself ]
end
```

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding your question, but it sounds like you just want to turn off wrapping:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#topology

Comment: I work in NetLogo 3D and I can't turn off wrapping (options are not available).

Comment: @Alan Do you know how I can change the options? Now they are inaccessible.

Comment: From the documentation: "Topologies are not yet supported in NetLogo 3D, so the world always wraps in all dimensions."

Comment: @Alan Thanks for help! And I am sorry, I overlooked that information.

Answer (score 1):

*edit:* Oh, you are in NetLogo 3D. That changes everything, unfortunately. Without being able to prevent the world from wrapping, there is no *easy* way of doing this. If you're feeling adventurous, you could try to find a way of ensuring that the nearest turtle is on the "right side of the wall" by triangulating with other turtles in the world. It wouldn't be easy though, but I could see that working. Good luck.

Outdated response:
I think the problem might be that in your `bounce` procedure, you have

```
set nearest-candidas max-one-of candidas [ distance myself ]
```

Using `max-one-of` sets the candidas to the one furthest AWAY from the neutrophil. You have it correctly in your `chase` procedure in which you set it to `min-one-of` (that is **min** one of, not **max** one of). Does changing that give you the behavior you were expecting?

Comment: If in 'bounce' procedure I change `max-one-of` for `min-one-of my` neutrophil would like bounce and bounce back wall in infinity, because he knows that the nearest target is located "behind the wall". When he bounces back again and again I wanted to he could change his target on another candida.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is my first model and I am not expert, so will try to find another way.